# Enqueue Custom script in the Wordpress Customizer

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, panel

Is there a way to `wp_enqueue_script()` and use it inside the Customizer Panel in Wordpress? Something like :

```
function myTheme_enqueue_script_admin() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-admin-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.min.js', array(), '1.0', true );
}
add_action('--ENQUEUE SCRIPT TO CUSTOMIZER--', 'myTheme_enqueue_script_admin');
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This query is more complete : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46506029/6693019

Answer (score 1):

yes, just use this hook

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'func' );
```

> read more from [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)