# wp_enqueue_script for widget form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget

I'm creating a widget and I need to enqueue a script for the widget form in the admin panel (and the customizer). I've tried a lot a ways :

```
function cf_enqueue_admin_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'wp-color-picker'), false, true);
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cfstcyr_admin_custom_script');
```

and

```
function cf_enqueue_admin_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('admin_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'wp-color-picker'), false, true);
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts-widgets.php', 'cf_enqueue_admin_script'));
```

and

```
class cfstcyr_plugin extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        add_action('admin_print_scripts-widgets.php', array(&$this, 'load_scripts'));
    }
    function load_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'wp-color-picker'), false, true);
    }
}
```

and

```
class cfstcyr_plugin extends WP_Widget {
    public function form() {
        ...
        wp_enqueue_script('admin_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/admin.js', array('jquery', 'wp-color-picker'), false, true);
    }    
}
```

It works but when I save without refreshing the page or when I'm in the Customizer it doesn't work.
I also tried this :

```
class cfstcyr_plugin extends WP_Widget {
    public function form() {
        ...
        <script type="text/javascript">
            ...
        </script>
    }    
}
```

But it triggers multiple time.

I really need to add Javascript (Media Uploader, Color Picker, etc) but I can't make it work after I've save the page without refreshing nor in the customizer.

So what I want is : my_custom_widget.php

```
class cfstcyr_plugin extends WP_Widget {
    public function form() {
       // Option form for widget
       <p>Click here!</p>
    }
}
```

and my widget.js

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.p').click(function() {
            alert('Hello World!');
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to import your custom scripts? Color picker and media uploader css and js files are prebuilt in WordPress you don't need to add them.

Comment: Yes, I want to add my own script.